# regex pattern to match particular uri from list of urls

Tags: java

I have a list of urls (lMapValues ) with wild cards like as mentioned in the code below
I need to match uri against this list to find matching url.

In below code I should get matching url as value of d in the map m.
That means if part of uri is matching in the list of urls, that particular url should be picked.

I tried splitting uri in tokens and then checking each token in list lMapValues .However its not giving me correct result.Below is code for that.

```
public class Matcher
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        Map m = new HashMap();
        m.put("a","https:/abc/eRControl/*");
        m.put("b","https://abc/xyz/*");
        m.put("c","https://work/Mypage/*");
        m.put("d","https://cr/eRControl/*");
        m.put("e","https://custom/MyApp/*");

        List lMapValues = new ArrayList(m.values());
        List tokens = new ArrayList();

        String uri = "cr/eRControl/work/custom.jsp";

        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(uri,"/");
        while(st.hasMoreTokens()) {

            String token = st.nextToken();
            tokens.add(token);
        }

        for(int i=0;i<lMapValues.size();i++) {
            String value = (String)lMapValues.get(i);
            String patternString = "\\b(" + StringUtils.join(tokens, "|") + ")\\b";
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternString);
            java.util.regex.Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(value);

            while (matcher.find()) {
                System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
                System.out.println(value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please help me with regex pattern to achieve above objective.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by is not giving the correct answer? Which is the correct answer? Can you provide examples of the inputs and expected outputs?

Comment: as I have mentioned input here is  String uri = "cr/eRControl/work/custom.jsp"; and it should return matching url as https://cr/eRControl/* from the list

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `i` is acting as a key not as an index on

```
String value = (String)lMapValues.get(i);
```

you will be better served exchanging the map for a list, and using the for each loop.

```
List<String> patterns = new ArrayList<String>();
...
for (String pattern : patterns) {
  ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's much simpler to check if a string starts with a certain value with `String.indexOf()`.

```
String[] urls = {
    "abc/eRControl", 
    "abc/xyz",
    "work/Mypage",
    "cr/eRControl",
    "custom/MyApp"
};

String uri = "cr/eRControl/work/custom.jsp";

for (String url : urls) {
    if (uri.indexOf(url) == 0) {
        System.out.println("Matched: " + url);
    }else{
        System.out.println("Not matched: " + url);
    }
}
```

Also. There is no need to store the scheme into the map if you are never going to match against it.

Answer (score 0):

if I understand your goal correctly, you might not even need regular expressions here.

Try this...

```
package test;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class PartialURLMapper {

    private static final Set<String> PARTIAL_URLS = new HashSet<String>();
    static {
        PARTIAL_URLS.add("cr/eRControl");
        // TODO add more partial Strings to check against input
    }
    public static String getPartialStringIfMatching(final String input) {
        if (input != null && !input.isEmpty()) {
            for (String partial: PARTIAL_URLS) {
                // this will be case-sensitive
                if (input.contains(partial)) {
                    return partial;
                }
            }
        }
        // no partial match found, we return an empty String
        return "";
    }
    // main method just to add example
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(PartialURLMapper.getPartialStringIfMatching("cr/eRControl/work/custom.jsp"));
    }

}
```

... it will return:

```
cr/eRControl
```